# HTML Diff Component for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, diff

Is anyone aware of a good managed code .NET component which can do HTML Diffs? I'd like to compare two HTML files and show the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a managed-code tool called [XmlDiffPatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx), which should work for HTML files as well.  You can run it as a stand-alone executable, or import the diff assemblies into your project.

Comment: XHTML is a subset of XML

Comment: @Steve : I think that tool is outdated and not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [htmldiff.net](https://github.com/Rohland/htmldiff.net) project out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a hosted solution, http://changedetection.com and http://imnosy.com both seem to look for diffs on pages.

Answer (score 0):

I tried **htmldiff.net** mentioned above but found the comparison to be vague and not descriptive enough for my needs.  I was concerned it might give false positive results, and I needed to be sure the comparison was correct even if the HTML was formatted slightly differently but rendered the same in the browser (ie. the sort order of attributes in tags were different, or different spacing between definitions in style attributes)

The only tool I found that could do this job properly was **HTML Tidy** ([www.html-tidy.org](http://www.html-tidy.org)).  It's not a HTML comparison tool as such, but it does provide a lot of control on how you tidy / clean / normalise HTML back to a normal form first, and then you implement your own comparision afterwards.

There are HTML Tidy wrappers for many languages.  I use **TidyHtml5ManagedRepack** (http://www.teosoft.it/TidyHtml5Managed).  It's available in NuGet in Visual Studio.

I have the following two methods in C# for normalising and cleaning HTML ...

```
public static string HtmlNormalise(this String html)
{
    Document doc = Document.FromString(html);
    doc.OutputBodyOnly = AutoBool.Yes;
    doc.Quiet = true;
    doc.AttributeSortType = TidyManaged.SortStrategy.Alpha;
    doc.DropEmptyElements = false;
    doc.DropEmptyParagraphs = false;
    doc.DropProprietaryAttributes = false;
    doc.MergeDivs = TidyManaged.AutoBool.No;
    doc.MergeSpans = TidyManaged.AutoBool.No;
    doc.WrapAt = 0;
    doc.Markup = true;
    doc.CleanAndRepair();
    return doc.Save().Replace("\r\n", "");
}

public static string HtmlClean(this String html)
{
    Document doc = Document.FromString(html);
    doc.OutputBodyOnly = AutoBool.Yes;
    doc.Quiet = true;
    doc.AttributeSortType = TidyManaged.SortStrategy.Alpha;
    doc.DropEmptyElements = false;
    doc.DropEmptyParagraphs = false;
    doc.DropProprietaryAttributes = false;
    doc.MergeDivs = TidyManaged.AutoBool.No;
    doc.MergeSpans = TidyManaged.AutoBool.No;
    doc.WrapAt = 0;
    doc.Markup = true;
    doc.MakeClean = true;
    doc.CleanAndRepair();
    return doc.Save().Replace("\r\n", "");
}
```

Using these methods I clean and then compare the HTML as strings like this ...

```
var Html1Cleaned = Html1.HtmlClean();
var Html2Cleaned = Html2.HtmlClean();

if (Html1Cleaned.Equals(Html2Cleaned))
    
    Console.WriteLine("Html1 and Html2 are the same");
else
   
    Console.WriteLine("Html1 and Html2 are different");
```

Or do the clean and compare in one operation like this ...

```
if (Html1.HtmlClean().Equals(Html2.HtmlClean()))
    
    Console.WriteLine("Html1 and Html2 are the same");
else
   
    Console.WriteLine("Html1 and Html2 are different");
```